# Python. Read a CSV File, compare to another and output to a txt file

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to create/learn how to write a program that will:

1. search a csv file with states, compare it to another file that has rollups to regions for states.  Then out put the results saying Region 1 = 50 Region 2 = 60 (a count..)

I've been able to get my program that can gather inputs, and write to a file on the search results.. but no luck so far in getting anything to work when searching another and giving the rollup & counts..   Any help is appreciated...

Here is my code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import csv
file = raw_input("Please enter the file name to search: ") #File name
save_file = raw_input("Please enter the file name to save: ") #Save Name
search_string = raw_input("Please type string to search for: ") #search string
#row = raw_input("Please enter column text is in: ") #column number - starts at 0
#ID_INDEX = row
#ID_INDEX = int(ID_INDEX)
f = open(file)
f1 = open(save_file, 'a')

#what looks for the string in the file
copyline=False
for line in f.readlines():
 if search_string  in line:
  copyline=True
  if copyline:
    f1.write(line)
f1.close() #close saved file
f.close() #close source file
```

Comment: Can you give some example input/output?

Comment: As an aside, it looks like the variable `copyline` isn't doing anything -- your `if search_string in line` takes care of it.

Comment: The program works.. it tosses out each line it sees something.. for example.. I type in CA and i will print out the lines where it sees CA (e.g. California, Cat, etc..) I copied the copyline code from another question (shortened the copyline from original though)  I just cant figure out how to write it to compare the search_string to  another csv file and pull back a different column..  sort of like a vlookup in excel.